# '70s or '80s sci-fi movie about a team captured by aliens after their spaceship crash-lands on a planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Not *Star Wars*. A sci-fi from '70s or '80s. A spaceship crashes on an alien planet. The head of the aliens sits in a big chair; he is monstrous, huge and scary. He orders for the team that was in the spaceship. They bring 3-4 pretty women in front of him, the women have bikini-like tops. He starts laughing and orders the women to take off their tops. The women look miniature in front of him.
Can anyone remember this movie?

Comment: Not exactly a match but the premise reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacehunter%3A_Adventures_in_the_Forbidden_Zone?wprov=sfla1

Comment: What kind of team were they? A sports team or a spaceship team/crew?

Comment: *Flesh Gordon*? It is a softcore porn *Flash Gordon* parody from 1974. I don't remember the boss villain as being particularly huge, but there is a huge humanoid monster later in the movie. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesh_Gordon

Comment: How those aliens look like?

Answer (score 2):

Could be [Spacehunter: Adventure in the Forbidden Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacehunter:_Adventures_in_the_Forbidden_Zone). From Wikipedia:

> Set in the early 22nd century, the film opens with the destruction of a space cruise liner by a bolt of nebular lightning. The only apparent survivors are three beautiful women — Nova, Reena, and Meagan — who abscond in an escape pod and land on the nearest habitable planet. There, they are quickly accosted by the hostile natives and taken aboard a sail-driven vehicle resembling a pirate ship on rails.

**The head of the aliens sits in a big chair; he is monstrous, huge and scary.**

The "alien" could be Overdog, played by Michael Ironside, though I believe they are actually post-apocalytpic mutant humans. Overdog is attached to a mechanical harness that moves him around his lair, and is mutated and ghoulish-looking, with giant claws for hands.

[image: Overdog]

**They bring 3-4 pretty women in front of him, the women have bikini-like tops. He starts laughing and orders the women to take off their tops.**

> In the meantime, the three women are taken before The Chemist, the chief henchman of Overdog who administers pacifying drugs to the women and prepares them for Overdog's pleasure.

This is from the beginning of the scene in question:
[image: Overdog captures three women]

**The women look miniature in front of him.**

While Overdog is a regular sized human, his harness and claws add to his size, and he is usually suspended above those around him, adding to the illusion of size.